# Can we place a middleman on whatever functions are returned by WGL, EGL, or CGL?

Tags: opengl, compatibility, support

I find myself wondering whether our PC games from the 2000s will continue to operate without a VM.

To the present, GPU manufacturers have generously kept pre-3.2 OpenGL in their drivers. I'm amazed and glad that they do.

But for argument's sake, imagine OpenGL<3.2 gets dropped. The current GL acquisition mechanism looks like this:

`App` → `calls wglGetProcAddress()` → `returns driver's GL functions`

**It's looks good at first, but legacy OpenGL support is entirely in the hands of the driver developer.**

This would be a non-issue if an "adapter" or "translation layer" could be set at runtime, positioned between WGL and the driver. For example: a enthusiast-maintained DLL that translates legacy API to new API.

Do any WGL/EGL/CGL implementations support user-specified adapters like that? (I see Mesa EGL has `EGL_BACKEND` but it only controls what hard-coded driver is selected)

Comment: I wouldn't be terribly surprised if most drivers' pre-3.2 support IS just such a translation layer, just loaded by the driver itself.  Have you looked into techniques like [DLL Injection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/178315/39518), which are already used to intercept driver calls from games?

Comment: @DMGregory Oh dang, I bet you're right about the drivers having a translation layer. That seems like a natural way to cut costs... Also, that DLL injection technique looks like a very practical solution to the issue! Maybe a skilled preservationist could supply their own opengl32.dll to intercept wgl functions! Thanks for the link!